# SMTP Mail Not Send in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In `Config.php` File I have changes

```
$config['protocol']='smtp';

$config['smtp_hostname'] = "ssl://smtp.zoho.com";

$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';

$config['smtp_username'] = "aaaa";

$config['smtp_password'] = "xxx";

$config['smtp_port'] = '465';

$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

But MAil Not Send.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KpSI.png)

Comment: Try with smtp_port 587 instead of 465

Comment: Please check email.php file in your config folder
if there are not email.php file copy email.php file from  
https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer/blob/master/config/email.php
and paste config folder.

Comment: change smtp_crypto from tls to ssl or change port to 587(tls),remove ssl:// from hostname,